# DRF: accessing a SerializerMethodField during serializer validation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django Rest Framework 3.0 and I have a model:

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    name = ...
    token = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

where `token` is a unique identifier that I generate from the `request` IP information to prevent the same user voting twice

I have a serializer:

```
class VoteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = ...
    token = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Vote
        fields = ("id", "name", "token")

    def validate(self, data):
        if Rating.objects.filter(token=data['token'], name=data['name']).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("You have already voted for this")
        return data

    def get_token(self, request):
        s = ''.join((self.context['request'].META['REMOTE_ADDR'], self.context['request'].META.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT', '')))
        return md5(s).hexdigest()
```

and a `CreateView`

But I am getting a

```
KeyError: 'token'
```

when I try to post and create a new `Vote`. Why is the `token` field not included in the data when validating?

[The docs mention](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield):

> It can be used to add any sort of data to the serialized representation of your object.

So I would have thought it would be also available during `validate`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Investigating, it seems that `SerializerMethodField` fields are called after validation has occurred (without digging into the code, I don't know why this is - it seems counter intuitive).

I have instead moved the relevant code into the view (which actually makes more sense conceptually to be honest).

To get it working, I needed to do the following:

```
class VoteCreateView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = VoteSerializer

    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # kwarg.data is a request MergedDict which is immutable so we have
        # to copy the data to a dict first before inserting our token
        d = {}
        for k, v in kwargs['data'].iteritems():
            d[k] = v
        d['token'] = self.get_token()
        kwargs['data'] = d
        return super(RatingCreateView, self).get_serializer(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_token(self):
        s = ''.join((self.request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'], self.request.META.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT', '')))
        return md5(s).hexdigest()
```

I really hope this isn't the correct way to do this as it seems totally convoluted for what appears to be a pretty straight forward situation. Hopefully someone else can post a better approach to this.

Comment: It's is about a long time, but do you know why? Because more than 6 years later it's the same...

Comment: The docs state that `SerializerMethodField` is read-only which explains why they aren't validated https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield 